# How can I unit test a react app using msw for mocking?

Tags: jestjs, msw

I'm trying to test a react app using msw to mock server responses and jest to run tests.

I want to access the dom so I need to use jsdom as a test environment. Any other environement (eg node) will get me this error :

> ```
> The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see     https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string.
> ```
>
> Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.
> >  ReferenceError: document is not defined

I can't use msw web workers in my jest unit tests because I get this error :

> ● Test suite failed to run

> Invariant Violation: [MSW] Failed to execute `setupWorker` in a non-browser environment. Consider using `setupServer` for Node.js environment instead.

```
  2 | import { setupWorker } from 'msw/browser';
  3 |
  4 | export const worker = setupWorker(...handlers);
```

I can't use msw server mode because it is not supported by the jsdom env

> ● Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot find module 'msw/node' from 'src/tests/mocks/server.ts'

Require stack:
  src/tests/mocks/server.ts
  src/tests/setupTests.ts

  1 | import { handlers } from './handlers';
> 2 | import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';
```

I'm using msw 2.0.0 and jest 29.7.0

Any hint on how to get this to work ?
Thank you !

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I'm having a similar issue and can't get my tests to run if I try to add `msw`.

Comment: @Esban unfortunately not. I gave up for now and I will pick this up later in the hope the issue will be addressed somehow in the meantime. If I do find a fix i'll post my updates in the answer section here :)

Comment: The migration guide explains how `Cannot find module 'msw/node'` could be solved in a JSDOM environment: https://mswjs.io/docs/migrations/1.x-to-2.x#cannot-find-module-mswnode-jsdom